# My search bar is not filtering any data from listview. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my onItemChanged() function and how to solve the issue?

Tags: flutter, searchbar

The app only shows listview but doesn't filter any data.
If I type anything in searchbar the list view remains same

[image: If I type anything in searchbar the list view remains same]

```dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => new _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Future<List> getData() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse("http://192.168.0.166/api/conn2.php"));

    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("MY APP"),
        ),
        body: Center(child: ListSearch()));
  }
}

class ListSearch extends StatefulWidget {
  ListSearchState createState() => ListSearchState();
}

class ListSearchState extends State<ListSearch> {
  TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();
  List newList = [];

  onItemChanged(String value) {
    setState(() {
      newList = MyStatelessWidget(
        list: [],
      )
          .list
          .where((string) => string.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()))
          .toList(); //copying api data into newList
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: TextField(
              controller: _textController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Search here....",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  onPressed: _textController.clear,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                ),
              ),
              onChanged: onItemChanged, //onItemChanged() called here
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: new FutureBuilder<List>(
              future: _HomeState().getData(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

                return snapshot.hasData
                    ? new MyStatelessWidget(
                        list: snapshot.data ?? [],
                      )
                    : new Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The database contains 'Articles','Features', 'Features2','Description' table

```
    class _ArticleDescription extends StatelessWidget {
      const _ArticleDescription({
        Key? key,
        required this.articles,
        required this.features,
        required this.features2,
        //required this.description,
    
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      final String articles;
      final String features;
      final String features2;
      // final String description;
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    articles,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2.0)),
                  Text(
                    features,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12.0,
                      color: Colors.black54,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    features2,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12.0,
                      color: Colors.black87,
                    ),
                  ),
                  /*Text(
                    description,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12.0,
                      color: Colors.black54,
                    ),
                  ),*/
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Custom list view

```
    class CustomListItemTwo extends StatelessWidget {
      const CustomListItemTwo({
        Key? key,
        required this.thumbnail,
        required this.articles,
        required this.features,
        required this.features2,
        // required this.description,
    
      }) : super(key: key);
      final Widget thumbnail;
      final String articles;
      final String features;
      final String features2;
      //final String description;
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 80,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 0.8,
                  child: thumbnail,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 2.0,0.0),
                    child: _ArticleDescription(
                      articles: articles,
                      features: features,
                      features2: features2,
                      // description: description,
    
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      final List list;
    //final  List<String> list;
    
    
      const MyStatelessWidget({ required this.list});
    
      //const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key, required this.list}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: list == null ? 0 : list.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: new GestureDetector(
                  onTap: ()=>Navigator.of(context).push(
                      new MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context)=> new Detail(list:list , index: i,)
                      )
                  ),
    
                  child:Column(
    
                    children:<Widget> [
                      CustomListItemTwo(
                        thumbnail: Container(
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
                        ),
    
                        articles: (list[i]['Articles']),
                        features: (list[i]['Features']),
                        features2: (list[i]['Features2']),
                        //description: (list[i]['Description']),
    
                      ),
    
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: you can achieve with when search button click change searchlist and then back return oldlist

Comment: 'ListView.builder(  
List viewlist; 
searchbar?viewlist = searchlist:viewlist=list;

Comment: Can you explain in details what should I do? actually I am a newbie in flutter.

Comment: Expanded(
            child: new FutureBuilder<List>(
              future: _HomeState().getData(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

                return snapshot.hasData
                    ? new MyStatelessWidget(
                        list: snapshot.data ?? [],  //--------what should I write here??

Comment: final response = // put some json data for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list == null ? 0 : list.length,
        ....
```

To

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var activeList = searchlist ;
  //create isSearchBar bool var. and change 
  //true if search is Active
  //false if search is inActive
  isSearchBar
    ? activeList = searchlist 
    : activeList  = list;
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: activeList == null ? 0 : activeList.length,
        ....
             articles: (activeList[i]['Articles']),
        ....
```